# Double quotes Miss Matching in Html fie While adding Django template keys on Visual studio Code

Tags: html, django, visual-studio

For the following HTML code, in `img` tag while adding a image path as template key, the double quotes are wrongly taken by the Visual Studio:

```
</h2>
  <img src="{% static "images\image.jpg" %}" alt="not available">
</body>
```

Comment: So what? It makes no difference. If it bothers you, use single quotes for one of the sets, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Answer (score 2):

It should take double quotes wrongly, because:

```
"{% static "images\image.jpg" %}"
^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^
```

Because they are two strings, not one inside another. So you should use it like this:

```
# either
"{% static 'images\image.jpg' %}"

# or

'{% static "images\image.jpg" %}'
```

Comment: But they aren't actually, because the inner set is processed by the template engine long before it gets to the browser. So the original code is perfectly valid, the only issue is the highlighting.